# How to select column from different tables based on condition in single query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is it possible to get the date column from the different table based on conditions in a single query?

1. In `SPE_common_data` is the Main table, there is `spe_content_type` column has `JOURNAL PAPER` or `CONFERENCE PAPER` are values.

[image]

2. If the column value is `JOURNAL PAPER` – use `SPE_journal_data` table and use `spe_journal_pub_online_date` as active date to publish paper
   [image]
3. IF the column value is `CONFERENCE PAPER` – use   `SPE_conference_data` table to find `spe_meeting_code` for that paper

[image]

4.And based on that `spe_meeting_code` go to `Petro_meetings` table and find `early_start_date` for that meeting code and use that date to publish that paper.

[image]

Is this possible for everything in a single query?

Comment: I think you can break your conditions and combine them with union.  For example join  `SPE_common_data ` and `SPE_journal_data` where `spe_content_type` is `JOURNAL PAPER` . This will be one of your results. Combine it with other ones with union

Answer (score 1):

Try to union two queries by the `set_content_type` value, for example like this:

```
SELECT 
  cmn.spe_manuscript_num,
  cmn.spe_content_type,
  jrn.spe_journal_pub_online_date AS pub_online_date 
FROM spe_common_data cmn
JOIN spe_journal_data jrn ON cmn.spe_manuscript_num = jrn.spe_manuscript_num
WHERE cmn.spe_content_type = 'JOURNAL PAPER'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  cmn.spe_manuscript_num,
  cmn.spe_content_type,
  pm.early_start_date AS pub_online_date 
FROM spe_common_data cmn
JOIN spe_conference_data cnf ON cmn.spe_manuscript_num = cnf.spe_manuscript_num
JOIN petro_meetings pm ON cnf.spe_meeting_code = pm.spe_meeting_code 
WHERE cmn.spe_content_type = 'CONFERENCE PAPER'
```